# Como passar um parâmetro para o controller que contem / (barra)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, parâmetros

Preciso passar um parâmetro para um `Controller`, porém, esse parâmetro contem / (barra).

Exemplo:

1. 5701/1_1
2. 5966/2_5
3. 7881/6_1

Para passar o parametro estou utilizando `@Url.Action`:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Visualizar", "DetailsRaWeb", new { id = item.TAG })
```

Mas, ao executar é gerado o erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tentou com HtmlEncode? https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/73z22y6h(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Aline tentei seguir a sua dica, mas o erro continua, utilizei: `@Html.ActionLink("Visualizar", "DetailsRaWeb", new { id = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(item.cod_item_CRM) })`

Comment: Não daria para substituir por outro caractere e na controller fazer o replace?

Comment: @ThiagoAraújo replace? vc diz, substituir na view, e no controler alterar para / (barra)?

Comment: isto... vc mandaria ao invés de barra, um caractere como '#' por ex. E na Controller, faria a substituição string.Replace("#", "/");